# What real world item is the most extreme 'matryoshka doll', i.e. object nested inside other objects?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

This is a problem that has been puzzling me for a while, however, I want to know what the 'biggest' real-world Matryoshka Doll is.

As an example I could have a pencil in a pencil case in my drawer in my desk in my room in my house. If I wanted I could also take the example of the pencil lead and get another layer of 'nesting'.

I have heard that the most times a piece of paper can be folded is seven times, any more than that and the height of the paper is several times the diameter of the known universe, so there is some limit there. I wonder if there is also a limit to the Matryoshka Doll 'nesting' scenario.

I don't care what the small object size is - it could be a chunk of a molecule - but I do want to know what the most nested item is on planet earth.

Comment: I'm... not entirely sure this is a world-building question, but I'm not sure where else this would be on-topic either.

Comment: The lead in the pencil should not count. It must be a pencil case in a pencil case in a pencil case.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The paper-folding myth was busted [by the Mythbusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAEBbotuIE). Beyond that, this does not appear to be a worldbuilding question. If you haven't already, I would suggest taking the [tour] and checking out what is [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the site.

Comment: @ Will I agree. If the objects aren't at least similar this exercise becomes rather arbitrary. The human body could be considered to have thousands of layers depending on how you look at it - but then, that human is also inside of other things. The atmosphere, the solar system, the galaxy. It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: Folding a paper seven times is "several times the diameter of the known universe"? It must be a very tiny universe...

Comment: Also, the main limiting factor for you Matryoshka Doll scenario is how similar the layers are obliged to be.  In the dolls, they're typically very similar, but there's differences in each layer.  If you don't address those limits, the answer is "the largerst obejct is the universe, and it nests down to any particular proton you please."

Comment: Sonotube style concrete forms are cardboard tubes.   They emphasize that the diameters are nominal, in actuality a 12" tube is +/- 1".  You see, shipping stiff bulky tubes is expensive, so they deliberately make them off-size so they can ship them with 6-8 of the tubes nested inside one another.

Answer (score 5):

[Dendrochronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochronology) is the scientific method of dating tree rings. As the tree ages, new growth occurs near the bark of the tree. Each year, a new ring (or "shell", "nest" if you want) encases the old rings.

Wikipedia indicates that the journal [here](https://journals.uair.arizona.edu/index.php/radiocarbon/article/view/16947/pdf) has the oldest tree ring measurements as around 13 900 years, but that number just refers to measurements.

[image]

[Live Science](https://www.livescience.com/29152-oldest-tree-in-world.html) says the oldest tree in the world is 5062 years old. You could use this as a rough number for number of nests.

Comment: But that span of 14 millennia is of course made up of _multiple_ trees, not one tree. The entire point of dendrochronology is to make it possible to place into correspondence the growth rings of one tree with those of another tree; in this way, when a piece of wood is found by archaeologists they can find out when the tree was cut.

Comment: @AlexP Good point, it was *measurements* and not the actual tree. I'll change the answer a bit.

Comment: Great job of making lemonade from lemons.

Answer (score 0):

Crystals have layers often one atom thick.  Even a small grain has a lot of layers.

The degenerate matter in some red supergiant cores should have a lattice structure.  If "biggest" means most massive then neutron stars.